# Form key not updating on each refresh in magento 2

Tags: magento2

For a specific reason, I have to create FormKey in my controller but it is not re generate on browser on each refresh.

FormKey generated but not updating. It showing the same key every time.

I am following below article.

```
https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/tip-getting-a-form-key-in-your-template/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can check `getFormKey` function in `\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey` class. There is already one check applied if it is created then return existing one OR create new key.

If you want to regenerate key for each request in your module, you can reset the `FORM_KEY` session value to `FALSE`. For this, you need to use the below code:

```
\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session
$this->session->setData($this->formKey::FORM_KEY, false);
```

Hope this help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the session dependency in your controller as like:

```
protected $session;
    protected $formKey;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $forKey
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->formKey = $forKey;
    }
```

Then in your function unset the form key using below code:

```
$formkey = '';
$this->session->setData(_form_key, '');
// Your code
$formkey = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
```